# How to always serve newest React bundle to client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, continuous-deployment

How to always serve newest uploaded React app for clients? Sometimes i updating my app, by simply uploading newest bundle to server. But when someone visiting my page see old version of App... Why?
How to always keep serving newest uploaded bundle for visitors?

It on applies visitor who already visited my page before.

I expect to serve always newest uploaded bundle for visitors

Comment: well, your webpack must do that job. but the normal rule is to add a version parameter to the end of the js, so the browser knows is a new file. like bundle.js?v=384u5834u58

Comment: Set a unique hash in the bundle filename, so that when new bundle is uploaded the browser cache is invalidated.
If you are using a modern bundler like webpack / parcel, rollup, it should be easily configurable.

Comment: You can take a look at this [guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/) from webpack